# Golang: How do I successfully create a new Stripe PaymentIntent in go? The example go code has an undefined variable named "paymentintent."

Tags: go, stripe-payments

The [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android-create-payment-intent) has the following code:

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
stripe.Key = "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc"

params := &stripe.PaymentIntentParams{
  Amount: stripe.Int64(1099),
  Currency: stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
}
pi, _ := paymentintent.New(params)
// Pass the client secret to the client
```

The issue I'm having is that `paymentintent` is undefined. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/tree/master/paymentintent

Comment: Thanks! I added `"github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v71/paymentintent"` to my imports and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code, Hope it helps.

install the following libraries from terminal,

```
go get github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v72
go get  github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v72/paymentintent
```

Now run the two commands from the terminal,

```
go mod it V1
go mod tidy
```

Now just add your secret keys and email ids to the following codes and execute it, you will get the response of the Payment Intent object.
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v72"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v72/paymentintent"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("here its payment processing")

    // Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
    stripe.Key = "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc"

    params := &stripe.PaymentIntentParams{
        Amount:   stripe.Int64(1000),
        Currency: stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
        PaymentMethodTypes: stripe.StringSlice([]string{
            "card",
        }),
        ReceiptEmail: stripe.String("your@mail.com"),
    }
    pi, _ := paymentintent.New(params)
    fmt.Println(pi)
}
```